# How can we reduce the spatial complexity of intermediate indexes in relational databases at execution time?

Tags: complexity-theory, optimization, space-complexity, database-theory, databases

In relational databases, what are the practical or theoretical ways to reduce the size and spatial complexity of intermediate indexes or tables* at execution time (so for example to reduce the size of intermediate indexes when running a join on a time series data with millions of entries).

Additional research papers or database documentations regarding this subject are very much appreciated, thank you!

*: I couldn't find an agreed upon term to use here, but I refer to what some DBMS creates during the evaluation of SELECT queries with joins and/or restrictions to improve the performance of the query, for example: Intermediate Table Index.

Comment: (*temporary* rather than *intermediate*?)